# Logstash add a field of type Date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have logs that contain time in the following format: `20231030 09:41:20.179021`. I want to parse these into the `Date` type in logstash.

This is my current filter

```
filter{ 
  grok { 
    match => { 
      "message" => "%{YEAR:year}(?<month>\d{2})(?<day>\d{2}) %{TIME:log_time}"
    }
  }
  mutate {
    add_field => {
      "mytime" => "%{year}-%{month}-%{day}T%{log_time}Z"
    }
    remove_field => ["day", "month", "year", "log_time"]
  }
  date {
    match => ["mytime", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ", "ISO8601"]
    timezone => "UTC"
    target => "mytime" 
  }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Although the field `mytime` gets added, it is not of type `Date`, instead is of type `Keyword`.

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your filters do the right job, however, your index must have been already existing with a keyword mapping prior to indexing your first document. I've tried this on a local ELK stack and `mytime` correctly gets created as `date`

Comment: I ran a fresh container after deleting the volume. Although, I do see a template that got created automatically due to the `ilm_enabled => "true"` option.  Is this the problem?

Comment: Yes, it might be, depending on what the template contains, it might create keyword fields if the content is text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is stated, if you haven't create a mapping, elasticsearch creates a **Dynamic Mapping** and index them as keyword or with other types automatically.
Here is the source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html

If you have already another mapping and you create new documents which does not fit current index and dynamic mapping is enabled, it still maps them dynamically.

What you should do is to create a mapping and tell elasticsearch how you want to map your fields. This is called **Explicit Mapping**.
Here is the source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/explicit-mapping.html

If you have just an index and want to map it, you can directly set your explicit mapping.

If you have 1 or more than one similar indices and want to map them explicitly, I recommend using **index templates**.

- You can find them in Kibana under **Stack Management** then **Index Management** section on the left side.
- Or you can use Kibana Dev Tools or similarly Postman to send your template.

If you have an existing index and want to map them with an explicit mapping, I  recommend using **Alias**, especially if you do not want to lose your data in the old index.

In this version:

- Create an alias MYALIAS for OLD_INDEX
- Create index template with NEW_INDEX
- Reindex it OLD_INDEX -> NEW_INDEX) using DEV TOOLS in Kibana
- Now you have two indices.
- Set your MYALIAS to NEW_INDEX and you are done.